# Integral $\int\limits_0^a x^b (1 - c x)^d\ \cosh x\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

How does one calculate

$$\frac{2\pi^{\frac{m-1}{2}}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{m-1}{2} \right)} \left(\frac{\alpha}{\kappa} \right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-1}\int\limits_0^{\kappa/\alpha}x^{m+\frac{1}{\alpha}-2}\cosh(x)\left(1-\left(\frac{\alpha}{\kappa}x\right)\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}dx ?$$

Comment: @M.cardirci:  You're new here, so let me instruct you on how to ask questions.  Your constants outside the integral are just that (irrelevant), so you should not include them in your question.  Likewise you can simplify your question to:  $$\int\limits_0^a x^b  (1 - c x)^d\ \cosh x\ dx .$$  Such a question focuses on the essence of your problem and will help you (and others) find a solution.  Compare my posing to yours and see which will attract more help...

Comment: Also, please do not just give an order like "Evaluate" or "Calculate." What have you tried? What makes you sure the integral can be calculated?

Comment: At first, your question consisted only of the integral without anything else. So @DavidG.Stork at least added one word to it. Still, it is your task to [add context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/) to the question by editing it 

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no context, there are no bounds on the parameters.  Consequently, I have invented bounds and evluated a closely related integral, which evaluation is dependent on those bounds.  If $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c > 0$, $\Re(b) > -1$, and $\Re(d) > -1$,

$$  \int_0^{1/c} \; x^b (1 - c x)^d \cosh(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = 2^{-1-b-d}c^{-1-b}\pi \Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(d+1) \cdot {}_2\overline{F}_3\left( \frac{b+1}{2}, \frac{b+2}{2}; \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}(b+d+2), \frac{1}{2}(b+d+3); \frac{1}{4 c^2} \right)  \text{,}$$
where ${}_p \overline{F}_q(\vec{a}; \vec{b}; z)$ is the [regularized generalized hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedHypergeometricFunction.html).

Answer (score 1):

Doing basically the same as @Eric Towers, for the integral 
$$I=\frac{2\pi^{\frac{m-1}{2}}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{m-1}{2} \right)} \left(\frac{\alpha}{\kappa} \right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-1}\int\limits_0^{\kappa/\alpha}x^{m+\frac{1}{\alpha}-2}\cosh(x)\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{\kappa}x\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\,dx $$
we have
$$I=K\, _2F_3\left(\frac{1}{2 \alpha }+\frac{m-1}{2},\frac{1}{2 \alpha
   }+\frac{m}{2};\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2 \alpha }+\frac{m}{2},\frac{3}{2 \alpha
   }+\frac{m+1}{2};\frac{\kappa ^2}{4 \alpha ^2}\right)$$
where
$$K=\frac 2 {\sqrt \pi}\left(\frac { \kappa\sqrt \pi}{\alpha}\right)^m \,\,\frac{ \Gamma \left(1+\frac{2}{\alpha }\right)\,
   \Gamma \left(m+\frac{1}{\alpha
   }-1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{m-1}{2}\right)\, \Gamma
   \left(m+\frac{3}{\alpha }\right)}$$

provided $\qquad \alpha  \kappa >0\land \Re\left(m+\frac{1}{\alpha }\right)>1\land
   \Re\left(\frac{1}{\alpha }\right)>-\frac{1}{2}$